# Why do we need to explicitly set OutputKey/InputKey Class in MapReduce job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Why do we need to explicitly set OutputKey/InputKey Class in MapReduce job when the Map and Reduce classes has to extend Mapper and Reducer classes respectfully that requires to add `<InputKeyClass, InputValueClass, OuputKeyClass, OutputValueClass>` ?

an example:

JobConf:

```
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Reducer:

```
public static class ComputeReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
```

If we are already explicitly setting the reducer class to extend `'Reducer <Text, Text, NullWritable, Text>'` then why is it required to pass the OutputKey/value class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do that because all generic information is lost at run time in java.